# @types/react-virtualized typings are producing TS errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-virtualized

I'm using:

- `typescript 2.1.6` (though I can reproduce this error with 2.4.0 as well)
- `react 15.6.1`
- `react-virtualized 9.9.0`
- `@types/react-virtualized 9.7.3`

TS is complaining about the following (example) code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { List, ListRowProps } from "react-virtualized";

class TestComponent extends React.PureComponent<{}, {}> {
    public render() {
        return (
            <List
                width={300}
                height={300}
                rowCount={100000}
                rowHeight={30}
                rowRenderer={this.rowRenderer}
            />
        );
    }

    private rowRenderer(props: ListRowProps) {
        return <div
                 key={props.key}
                 style={props.style}
               />;
    }
}
```

Specifically, it gives me this error:

```
error TS2605: JSX element type 'List' is not a constructor function for JSX elements.
```

Notably, if I go in and edit `List.d.ts` directly I can fix it by changing:

```
export class List extends PureComponent<ListProps> {
```

to

```
export class List extends PureComponent<ListProps, {}> {
```

which makes sense to me given that the definition of `PureComponent` is

```
class PureComponent<P, S> extends Component<P, S> { }
```

i.e. `PureComponent` requires two type parameters, so a class cannot extend `PureComponent<T>` but it can extend `PureComponent<T, {}>`.

Are my assumptions correct? Is there a bug in `@types/react-virtualized` caused by an attempt to extend `PureComponent<ListProps>`? Or am I using incompatible versions of these packages? Or is there a TypeScript setting that I need to be using to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out!

I was using an outdated version of `@types/react`. Bumping it to the most recent version fixed my issue.